# What is the optimal number of worker tasks to specify in MySQL Workbench for a speedy migration?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

What is the optimal number of worker tasks to specify in MySQL Workbench for a speedy migration?

The default is 2.

The MySQL server is running on the same Windows machine, installed with defaults.  It has 8 vCPUs and 61GB memory.

Answer (score 3):

There is a one worker per table limitation, so the maximum number depends on the number of tables you are migrating.

Notes:

- A decent maximum is the number of cores on your system
- If you specify a large number but have fewer tables, then only the needed threads will be launched
- If the network saturates, like maybe 20 tables with 20 workers, then the copy may actually be slower

So, there isn't a simple answer but hopefully this helps. For additional details, see [the related wbcopytables documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wbcopytables.html).